# Scan a DynamoDB table with a HashKey?

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to scan a DynamoDB table with a given HashKey? I have a table with a HashKey and a RangeKey and want to scan everything with a given HashKey. I can use scan with a filter, but that seems to scan all the tables -- even though it is partitioned on HashKey. This results in a lot of extra HTTP calls paging through empty results.

I could create an Index for this, but it seems silly since DynamoDB already must know the segmentation on HashKey.

I'm using boto with Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query without an index in which cast the primary key of the table is compared. Specify the HashKey comparison and omit the RangeKey to get all items with that HashKey.

In boto this just means leaving off the `index_name`.